# Existential types for F-Bounded Polymorphic types and non-generic subtypes?

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism, existential-type, subtype

I have two subtypes that I need to be F-bounded polymorphic by a type `A`, and a subtype of one of those subtypes, i.e.

```
trait A[T <: A[T]] {
  def x: T
}
trait Ter extends A[Ter]
trait For extends A[For]
trait C extends Ter
```

Next I try to implement a concrete type

```
case class F2(l: List[A[_]]) extends For {
  def x: For = F2(l.map(_.x))
}
```

But this fails to compile with:

```
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Any]
 required: List[A[_]]
         def x: For = F2(l.map(_.x))
                              ^
```

So, google says I need to use existential types, which makes sense, so I try:

```
import scala.language.existentials

type SomeA = T forSome { type T <: A[T] }

case class F1(l: List[SomeA]) extends For {
  def x: For = F1(l.map(_.x))
}
```

But, now I face a new problem when I try to instantiate

```
trait Example {
  val b: Ter
  val c: C
  val d: For

  // Works fine
  val l1: List[A[_]] = List(b, c, d)
  // But this doesn't work, fails to compile (see below)
  val l2: List[SomeA] = List(b, c, d)

  val f1 = F1(l2)
}
```

The compile error:

```
<console>:22: error: type mismatch;
 found   : C
 required: SomeA
    (which expands to)  T forSome { type T <: A[T] }
         val l2: List[SomeA] = List(b, c, d)
                                       ^
```

Why do I get this error? Surely `C` is a subtype of `Ter`, which in turn is a subtype of `A[Ter]`, therefore `C` is a subtype of `A[Ter]`, therefore there exists a `T` namely `Ter` such that `C` is a subtype of `A[T]`, therefore `C` is a subtype of `SomeA`.

It's as if the transitivity of subtyping isn't working.  When I hack it with `c.asInstanceOf[SomeA]` my code compiles and my unit tests pass.  Could it be a compiler bug?

I also thought that `List[A[_]]` was stronger typing than `List[SomeA]`, i.e. the former was saying the list consists of `A[T]` some *fixed* type `T`, where the latter is saying the list consists of `A[T]` where `T` is *not fixed*.

**BOUNS** If you can explain *why* the currently accepted answer works, i.e. why the compiler cannot work out that the type is valid without the ascription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the compiler needs some help. The following should work:

```
val l2 = List[SomeA](b, c: Ter, d)
```

Comment: Nope :(. Try it in a shell, I get 
`<console>:24: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[A[_ >: For with Ter <: A[_ >: For with Ter <: Object]]]
 required: List[SomeA]
    (which expands to)  List[T forSome { type T <: A[T] }]
       val l2: List[SomeA] = List(b, c: Ter, d)
                                 ^`

Comment: Also, I would prefer a way where I can avoid up casting.

Comment: Did you try `val l2 = List[SomeA](b, c: Ter, d)` instead of `val l2: List[SomeA] = List(b, c: Ter, d)`? I don't know how to avoid the type cast. At least it is checked at compile time unlike `c.asInstanceOf[Ter]`.

Comment: Yup, my bad, thanks. Accepting this answer since it does indeed get around `asInstanceOf` and is indeed type checked.  Nevertheless I'd like to better understand *why* the compiler cannot work this out itself.  Why do I have to ascribe the type? Is it just that they have not yet implemented this level of inference yet??

Comment: Thank you! I also would like to know why the compiler cannot work this out itself.