# strange compilation error with scala existentials with f bounded polymorphism

Tags: scala, existential-type, f-bounded-polymorphism

Why does the code below not compile ?

```
  trait B[T <: B[T]]
  case class A[T <: B[T]](t: T)

  class C() extends B[C]
  val c: C = new C()

  val r2: A[_]         = A(c)     //compiles
  val r3: A[_]         = A(c)     //compiles fine
  val r4: A[_]         = r3       //compiles fine
  val r5: (A[_])       = (r3)     //compiles fine
  val r6: (A[_], A[_]) = (r3, r3) // does not compile, strange
```

It gives:

```
Error:(68, 22) type arguments [_$7] do not conform to class A's type parameter bounds [T <: _experiment.akka_persistence.Test2.B[T]]
  val r6:(A[_],A[_])=(r3,r3)
```

EDIT:

Here is a related, self contained code snippet:

```
  import scala.language.existentials


  trait B[T <: B[T]]
  case class A[T <: B[T]](t: T)

  class C() extends B[C]
  val c: C = new C()
  type SomeB = T forSome { type T <: B[T] }
  val r3: A[_<:SomeB]         = A(c)     //compiles fine
  val r4: A[C]         = A(c)     //compiles fine
  val r5: (A[_<:SomeB])       = (r3)     //compiles fine
  val r6:((_<:SomeB),((_<:SomeB))) = (c,c)  // compiles fine
  val r7:(A[_<:SomeB],((_<:SomeB))) = (A(c),c)  // compiles fine
  val r8:(A[_<:SomeB],(A[_<:SomeB])) = (A(c),A(c))  // compiles fine
  val r10:(A[_<:SomeB],(A[_<:SomeB])) = (A(c),r4)  // compiles fine
  val r9:(A[_<:SomeB],(A[_<:SomeB])) = (A(c),r3)  // does not compile
```

- It seems that `r4` has to have type of `A[C]` and then `r10` compiles.
- So this suggests that `A[_<:SomeB]` for `r3` is not specific enough. But why not ?
- Also why is `A[_<:SomeB]` enough for `val r5: (A[_<:SomeB])       = (r3)` but not for `r9` ?

Comment: hmmm, this seems to be slightly relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674486/existential-types-for-f-bounded-polymorphic-types-and-non-generic-subtypes

Comment: Looks like another bug. Your first snippet compiles fine with dotty/master.

Comment: Hmm.... strange... should I start to use dotty ? :)

Comment: Should I submit some bug report ?

Comment: You might get a better answer reporting an issue than here on SO...

Comment: Yeah, I was not sure if it is a bug or what ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `r4` and `r5` are actually equivalent.  To declare a val of type `Tuple1` you need to be explicit:

```
val r5: Tuple1[A[_]] = Tuple1(r3)
```

And you will then discover that it also fails with the same error.

In REPL:

```
scala> Tuple1(r3)
<console>:24: warning: inferred existential type (A[_$1],) forSome { type _$1 }, which cannot be expressed by wildcards,  should be enabled
by making the implicit value scala.language.existentials visible.
This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.existentials'
or by setting the compiler option -language:existentials.
See the Scaladoc for value scala.language.existentials for a discussion
why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
       Tuple1(r3)
             ^
<console>:24: error: type arguments [_$1] do not conform to class A's type parameter bounds [T <: B[T]]
       Tuple1(r3)
       ^
```

You see that given existential typed `r3` the compiler inferred the tuple as `(A[_$1],) forSome { type _$1 }`.

This case is indeed similar to the one from @jhegedus ([Existential types for F-Bounded Polymorphic types and non-generic subtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674486/existential-types-for-f-bounded-polymorphic-types-and-non-generic-subtypes)), and the same solution applies i.e. give the compiler some help by explicitly specify the type param of `Tuple1`:

```
val r5 = Tuple1[A[_]](r3)
```

Or give `r3` a more specific type:

```
val r3: A[C] = A(c)
val r5: Tuple1[A[_]] = Tuple1(r3)
```

And the same goes for `r6` / `Tuple2`